# Javascript; how can I make a function globally accessible?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

1. I am trying to learn from this stopwatch example. I would like to be able to start the stopwatch by clicking on another html element, that is not defined on this page.
2. How can I use the 'start' function elsewhere ( e.g. page reload etc. ) ?

   ```
   var Stopwatch = function(elem, options) {

     var timer       = createTimer(),
         startButton = createButton("start", start),
         offset,
         clock,
         interval;

     // append elements     
     elem.appendChild(startButton);

     reset();

     // private functions
     function createTimer() {
       return document.createElement("span");
     }

     function createButton(action, handler) {
       var a = document.createElement("a");
       a.href = "#" + action;
       a.innerHTML = action;
       a.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
         handler();
         event.preventDefault();
       });
       return a;
     }

     function start() {
       if (!interval) {
         offset   = Date.now();
         interval = setInterval(update, options.delay);
       }
     }         

     // public API
     this.start  = start;
   };

   var d = document.getElementById("d-timer");
   dTimer = new Stopwatch(d, {delay: 1000});
   dTimer.start();
   ```

Q1: How will I be able to call the start function elsewhere ? Global ?

Comment: I believe you need to study JavaScript more yourself. Answering this will require to teach you a lot of things together, or you'll get an answer that you won't understand at all.

Comment: Javascript runs within a execution context, for browsers that's generally within a document. What structure are you proposing so that you can call the function from elsewhere (iframe? child window?). The *dTimer* object is global, and *start* is public, any context that has access to *dTimer* can call *start* (e.g. any function anywhere else in the document after the initial assignment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "not defined on this page" you mean the browser page as in the HTML document, then this is impossible. As soon as you switch the page (or even reload the page) the code will run in a different context.

Assuming this is what you want, you could work around this by not actually leaving the page, but instead loading another page and replacing the current pages content.

If you are not leaving the page, your dTimer object should be globally accessible.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign it to the window scope by doing:

```
window.functionName = function(){
  //your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually a misspelled "id" value.

Certainly it would be helpful to study javascript in detail, as Matias suggested.